# Invariant Violation Invalid hook call error on deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My app was working as aspected till the last commit.

Now it works fine on `npm start`, but after deploying it with `npm run builder` I get runtime error:

> Invariant Violation: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
>
> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

[Errors Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYT6Q.png)

Which leads to `Invalid Hook Error`

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

To try and address the issue I added eslint rule `"react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error"`.

Seems like my project is clean of `Invalid hooks errors` (it works fine on `npm start` as mentioned).

```
//package.json
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_PATH=src/ PORT=9050 react-app-rewired start",
    "builder": "NODE_PATH=src/ react-app-rewired --max_old_space_size=4096 build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build": "./dockerfile/build.sh simulator",
    "start:server": "node ./server/server.js",
  }
```

Any clue how to fix the deployment error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by upgrading `react-scripts`, `npm install react-scripts@latest`.

Then, you should Clear cache (`Application` tab in dev tools) and hard reload (`Ctrl+Shift+R`)

Comment: Don't forget to 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload' -- then it will work.